# Learning Delegates and Event Handlers, having issue with message not being shown

Tags: visual-studio, delegates, event-handling

I am getting a crash course in delegates and event handlers and I have been following a tutorial on the subject and trying to plug in what I have learned into a socket server program I am creating.

I am trying to decouple my server from knowing about the AlertConnectionOpened class here:

```
namespace AlertConnectionOpened
{
//This is a subscriber class

public class AlertConnectionOpened
{
    public void OnConnectionOpened(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection is opened");
    }
}

}
```

So I am using a delegate in my server class to accomplish this.

```
    namespace Server
{
public class RunServer
{


    // State object for reading client data asynchronously
    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client  socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {
        // Thread signal.
        public ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public AsynchronousSocketListener(int port)
        {
        }

        //This defines the delegate
        //Agreement between publisher and subscriber
        //object, source of event or class publishing or sending data, 
        //second param is any additional data we need to send.

        public delegate void ConnectionOpenEventHandler(string Message);

        //Indicates something has happened and finished.
        //Event defined here, based on delegate

        public event ConnectionOpenEventHandler ConnectionOpened;

        //Raise the Event, need a method to do this.
        //Responsible for notifying subscribers
        protected virtual void OnConnectionOpened()
        {
            if (ConnectionOpened != null)
                ConnectionOpened("Connection Opened");
        }



        public void StartListening()
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
            int port = 11000;

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            // The DNS name of the computer
            // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                //backlog of how many clients to take in
                listener.Listen(100);

                while (true)
                {
                    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                    allDone.Reset();

                    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    listener.BeginAccept(
                        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                        listener);

                    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.

                    allDone.WaitOne();
                    OnConnectionOpened();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();

        }

        public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Signal the main thread to continue.
            allDone.Set();

            // Get the socket that handles the client request.
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }

        public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            String content = String.Empty;

            // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the client socket. 
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                    state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                // more data.
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    // All the data has been read from the 
                    // client. Display it on the console.
                    Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                        content.Length, content);
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    content = rand.ToString();
                    // Echo the data back to the client.
                    Send(handler, content);
                }
                else {
                    // Not all data received. Get more.
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        public void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }


        public static int Main(String[] args)
        {
            AsynchronousSocketListener a = new AsynchronousSocketListener(0);
            a.StartListening();

            return 0;
        }







    }
}


}
```

Here is also my main program:

```
    namespace AppStart
{
class ServerStart 
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {



        RunServer.AsynchronousSocketListener svr1 = new RunServer.AsynchronousSocketListener(11000);//publisher

        //Correct the port number so a second server can open
        RunServer.AsynchronousSocketListener svr2 = new RunServer.AsynchronousSocketListener(350);

        svr1.StartListening();//publisher
        //This creates the subscriber
        var alertConnectionOpened = new AlertConnectionOpened.AlertConnectionOpened();//subsciber

        //make publisher register the handler for the event.
        svr1.ConnectionOpened += alertConnectionOpened.OnConnectionOpened;  //POinter to method

        svr2.StartListening();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }


}


}
```

From the little I understand of this my call to OnConnectionOpened();, should be showing the message that there is now a connection, but it isn't.

Comment: Subscribe the event *before* you call StartListening().  And use the debugger, set a break on OnConnectionOpened and you would have easily discovered the bug yourself.

Comment: Wow, that did it, thanks!